# Rethinkdb -- how to recover the accident deleted docs

Tags: rethinkdb

I just delete a whole table in production... How could I perform a recovery or undo that delete ?

> There is no  backup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sucks!  Unfortunately RethinkDB doesn't keep data around after you delete it.  Sometimes deleted data is still on disk somewhere if it hasn't been overwritten yet.  If you google "{NAME OF YOUR OPERATING SYSTEM} recover deleted data" you should be able to find instructions on how to get everything salvageable.  I'd recommend trying to keep write load as low as possible on the disk until you manage to recover whatever you can.